# jQuery/JS – scroll to next element on click (scrollable div issues)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple blog, and each blog post has a number of images ranging from 1 to 10. If you click on any of the images in the post, it should scroll you down to the next post. I thought something as simple as this would've worked:

```
$('.each-journal-entry .slider-container .journal-slider .each-slide img').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $('.journal-container').animate({
        scrollTop: $this.closest('.each-journal-entry').next().offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

But when I click another image, except for the first one, it just scrolls to an odd position.

I managed to achieve this with some help, and you can see the output here: http://jsfiddle.net/w7rtcmp0/3/ which works great, but the difference for me is that my content is in a scrollable div (hence `.journal-container` and not `html, body`.

Any ideas why I am having this issue? I have created a jsFiddle with the scrollable div, and if you click an image further down... it replicates this issue... so hopefully this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/w7rtcmp0/5/

Thanks.

Comment: Did you plug it into a `$(window).load()`?

Comment: @DOCASAREL I haven't... should I? I thought the `.on` function would resolve this?

Comment: @braw, you're fine.  It's not the load that's an issue.

Comment: I would have used id's and anchors haha.

Comment: @AndrewIce I'm thinking this might be the wise move too. So if I click on an image it could go to the new hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery adjusts `offset().top()` based on the current scroll position.

Using JavaScript's `offsetTop` property should fix the problem:

```
scrollTop: $this.closest('.each-journal-entry').next()[0].offsetTop
```

Fiddle:  **http://jsfiddle.net/m7cm5oL6/**

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at [Ariel Flesler's jQuery `scrollTo` plugin](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/), I had the same issue and using this saved me hours of debugging.

Answer (score 0):

So I think you were trying to use the wrong height.

Here I set a variable of height and set it to the height of the current journal/blog object.  This allows me to scroll my height all the way down to the next available blog object.

http://jsfiddle.net/w7rtcmp0/24/

```
$('.each-journal-entry .slider-container .journal-slider .each-slide img').on('click', function()     {
  $this = $(this);
  var height = $this.closest('.each-journal-entry').height();

  $('.scrollable').animate({
    scrollTop: height
  }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: This works if there are only two journal entries, but it won't for subsequent entries.